# Where is the link for the Ubuntu One for Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu-one

I used to know where it was but can't find it, any help please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Direct link to the installer: https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/windows/install/

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/?p=689.
The download link is at the bottom.

Comment: i'm getting a Error establishing a database connection